# Counting the number of options in a select drop down (multiple on same page)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to output the number of options in a select drop down, but there are multiple ones on the same page.

For example:

```
<select name="select" class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
</select>

<select name="select" class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 2"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 3"></option>
</select>
```

So the first one would output (1) and the second would output (3).

I have this code but it outputs (4) - counting all options from all selects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $(".date_number").text($(".drop option").length + " items");
});
</script>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Where's the `.date_number` element with respect to your example? And how do you decide which `select` you are referring to?

Comment: what do you want exactly? if you want to counting your selects options you can create loop and plus your options. \

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the selector `".drop option"` will get **all** the `option` elements *under* (not necessarily direct children) of an element with class `".drop"`.

Note that this does not only is valid for select element but also with this:

```
<div class="drop">
    <select>
        <option>Item 1</option>
        <option>Item 2</option>
        <option>Item 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

$('.drop option').length // 3
```

To ensure your `<option>` elements children of `<select class="drop">`, use the children selector `>`:

```
$('.drop > option');
```

---

To get separately the amount of options for each select, you would select the `<select>` first and then count for each of then. You can do something like:

```
var optionsArr = $('select.drop').map(function() {
                     return $(this).find('option:not(:disabled)').length;
                 }).toArray();
```

This will return an array with the different amounts: `[1, 3]`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/JUqJd/)**

---

To add a div with the the text "3 date(s) available", do this:

```
$('select.drop').each(function() {
    // the current select.drop
    var $this = $(this);
    // create a div with the text you want
    $('<div>' + $this.find('option:not(:disabled)').length + ' date(s) available</div>')
        // append it after the current select.drop
        .insertAfter($this);
});
```

///////////////////////

Ok, nearly there!  Thanks again for your time on this...

I have put the code in and it is doing what I want it to do, however due to the fact that it is all in an Accordion, it loops each time for each accordion item.  See screenshot (excuse styling):

[image: Screenshot]

I just need it to now only loop for the select drop in that accordion, rather than for each one.

Also, in my Select fro down, I have the first Option as "Disabled" as part of the validation so that the user has to select an item before continuing, such as:

```
<option disabled="disabled"></option>
```

The javascript is also counting this.  So is there any way we can put a -1 in there to the result, or is there a better way of doing this that I am missing?

Thanks again...

Comment: Many thanks for this....  It work for outputting the values as an alert, however, how would I get the values into a div to display?  Basically, the select drop downs are a list of available dates for each category of event, and I would like it to say "3 dates available" or "1 date available" next to each category depending on how many options there are in each?  thanks for your time!

Comment: P.S...I cannot set individual ID's for the select drop downs as they are dynamically created by a CMS - not hard coded.

Comment: Thanks Didier...I have added my response below your answer.  Thanks very much again...

Comment: You're welcome. Though I can't write all your code for you, this is not goal. I think you have a pretty good start to tweak your script to achieve what you want now. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Ok...I have accepted your answer.  Thanks.  If you could give me the little bit of code to stop it looping through them all..that would be great.  I can figure the rest out myself but I am stuck on this bit!  thanks

Comment: I can't really without seeing your code for the accordion. But for the disabled options you can do `$this.find('option:not(:disabled)').length`. PS: be careful when you edit posts, you erased my link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok that's great thanks for that.  Your code works fine, when you use .insertAfter($this);, however when I change this to .insertAfter('.title'); (where i want the value to be displayed) it does what the screenshot shows and shows the results for every select drop.  Apologies for deleting your link! :-/

Comment: Well, you are inserting after **all** elements with class "title"... Think of what you have to do: you want to set the text of the next element with class "title" -> ask yourself how to get the next element with class "title" and how to set its text ([traversing in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/))

Comment: Ok thanks... I have been trying to use the .next method but can't figure out how to get it into a div I want.  I'll keep looking and eventually get there!  Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 3):

It´s very easy, you only have to get length value from option:selected, like this:

$('.drop option:selected').length

I hope this be useful.

Comment: this will not count the number of options in the select.

Comment: Will count the number of selected options, sorry i think dont understood very weel the question.

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You get `4` because your jQuery selector matches for all the options on your page.

The basic question is, which `select` you want count ?

The best, for search engine optimization (for example), is you give the selects different ids.
But you can use other jQuery selectors like `:eq()`, `:first`, `:last` or otherl too. It depends on what you want to do.

#### Samples

**Different IDs's**

```
<select id="select1" name="select" class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select" class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 2"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 3"></option>
</select>

<span class="date_number"/>

$(function() {
  $(".date_number").text($("#select2 option").length + " items")
});
```

#### Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/AftpY/)

**:last Selector**

```
$(function() {
    $(".date_number").text($(".drop:last option").length + " items")
});
```

#### Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/AftpY/1/)

#### More Information

- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a unique id for each select, you'd have to do something like:

```
$('.drop').text( function(){
  console.log($(this).select('option').length);
  // instead of console.log return the text you want
  // return $(this).select('option').length + " items";
});
```

What this does is for each .drop class, it runs the function defined. The function is find all the  elements scoped within $(this). $(this) is the current .drop class element.

And the $('.drop') will run for every .drop class it finds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  How would I get the returned value to display in a positioned div within the accordion?